# Using socat to access X remotely

Tags: namespaces, socat, x11-forwarding

I have a remote server on which I want to launch some gui applications inside a network namespace I have already setup. I am using socat to forward the x session.

```
socat  exec:'ssh {REMOTE_HOST} rm -rf /tmp/.X11-unix/X1; socat -d -d -d -d unix-l\:/tmp/.X11-unix/X1111 -' unix:/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
```

However, if I try to launch an application like `eog`

```
DISPLAY=:1111 eog
```

It fails with the following message:

```
I   No protocol specified
** (eog:9498): WARNING **: Could not open X display
Cannot open display:
Run 'eog --help' to see a full list of available command line options.
```

And `socat` exits immediately afters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it took a day but I figured a way to do it.

I ended up using [Xpra](http://xpra.org/) to start an X-server at the remote server and attached to it in my local machine.

The socat approach worked too after running `xhost +` locally and adding the `fork` flag in the `socat` invocation at the remote server . However, it never worked consistently (There was as much chance the application to hang during launch as not). And it never worked with more complex applications like firefox. Stracing the apps pointed towards the applications hanging when trying to use dbus.